# Show window alert if username / email doesn't match specific domains

Tags: javascript, auth0, auth0-lock

I'd like to show an alert window on Auth0 universal lock if a domain in the email address field doesn't match to one from a specified list. Auth0 rules only run once authentication has taken place, I'd like something to happen before that, so I think a window alert might be a useful thing.

I've found this on the Auth0 forum which works for a single domain, in this case 'test.com' but I'd like to check multiple domains.

```
lock.once('signin ready', function() {
    document.querySelector("div.auth0-lock-container input[name='email']").addEventListener('change',function(event){
        var username = this.value;
        var getDomain = function(email) { return email.match(/@(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/i);};
        if (getDomain(username) !== 'test.com') {
            window.alert("Please make sure you're using an approved email address");
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried this as the if statement, but the window.alert shows for any domain, rather than the specific ones.   Is that because the regex is incorrect or the if statement?

```
lock.once('signin ready', function() {
    document.querySelector("div.auth0-lock-container input[name='email']").addEventListener('change',function(event){
        var username = this.value;
        var getDomain = function(email) { return email.match(/@(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/i);};
        if (!['companya.com', 'somecompany.net', 'anothercompany.org'].includes(getDomain(username))) {
            window.alert("Please make sure you're using an approved email address");
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex seems correct on first look, but the `String.match`(and therefore also the function `getDomain()`) does not return just a single string, but an array which contains further information about the match (or `null`) if there was no match (for instance not a valid email address at all). The first element of the array contains the matched string. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

So you have to check first whether the return value is not null and then take the first element of the array and check with your allowed domains

```
var m = username.match(/@(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/i);

if (!m || !["domain1.com", "domain2.com", ...].includes(m[0])) {
    window.alert("Please use ...");
}
```

Comment: Ah brilliant I see what you mean.  That works just fine, thanks very much derpirscher!